# Sharing a vBulletin page no longer works

Tags: facebook

I have been using a Like and Share button, in my forums site for some time now, and it worked just fine, until January 9th (that's the date of my last share, from my forums site to my Facebook page).

Today, when I went check some features, I saw that the Share link no longer works. I get some strange errors in the Debugger, such as Response code 500, missing og:type property, inferred og:url and og: title. Scraper is also not able to visit the pages, showing a "Document returned no data" error. The page renders fine if I open it in a browser window and here is what the page source looks like:

```
========== page souurce code start ==================
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" dir="ltr" lang="en" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta id="e_vb_meta_bburl" name="vb_meta_bburl" content="http://forum.m1911.org" />
<base href="http://forum.m1911.org/" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
<meta name="generator" content="vBulletin 4.2.2" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1409563412612912" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The M1911 Pistols Organization Forums Site" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is the M1911.ORG Forums Site, a discussion board for all those interested in the M1911 pistol, its variances, its accessories and parts, its gunsmithing, usage etc. A complimentary site to our Home Page and our E-zine. M1911.ORG is an Internet organization, with all you ever wanted to know about the M-1911 pistol, designed by the most ingenious gunsmith of all times, John Moses Browning." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://forum.m1911.org/showthread.php?105940-38-super-firing-pin" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://forum.m1911.org/images/facebook_image_share.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="38 super firing pin" />
================= end of code part ===================
```

The strange thing is that today, I upgraded another site I own, and in which I am using the same Facebook application, and that one works fine, with similar page source code shown (below).

```
========== page souurce code start ==================
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" dir="ltr" lang="en" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta id="e_vb_meta_bburl" name="vb_meta_bburl" content="http://ezine.m1911.org" />
<base href="http://ezine.m1911.org/" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
<meta name="generator" content="vBulletin 4.2.2" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1409563412612912" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="M1911.ORG E-zine" />
<meta property="og:description" content="http://i579.photobucket.com/albums/ss238/Onufriyenko/logos/wilson_combat.jpg 

Wilson Combat Drop-In Grip Safeties 

http://i579.photobucket.com/albums/ss238/Onufriyenko/Articles/WilsonGripSafety/PICT0002.jpg 

Drop-in … or not? 

Reviewed for M1911.ORG by Harwood Loomis" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://ezine.m1911.org/showthread.php?187-Wilson-Combat-Drop-In-Grip-Safety" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://forum.m1911.org/images/facebook_image_share.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Wilson Combat Drop-In Grip Safety" />
============ end of page code ===========
```

Also, the sharing image I have is not recognized by the program, as if it's not there.

Any ideas what can be wrong? Is it my site or is it Facebook?!??!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, Facebook look at your website as a guest so you need to be sure that guests can see thumbnail and attachment if you want Facebook to use either.

You can use this debug tool from Facebook and see what the missing things are: [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

if you are sure what issues you have, then things easily can be fixed.